# AtTask API get project information from task query

Tags: attask

The way that our team works is; a single project is created with multiple sub tasks that are assigned to different teams. I'm trying to build an application to help my team get a birds eye view of how many subtasks we have assigned to us by specific criteria. That part is easy. However, we need our query to return projects expected completion date, not that of the subtask as this is how we base our releases.

How can I efficiently get the data of the subtasks parent project?

An example of the query i'm currently using is:
/task/search?name=Name of Task&percentComplete=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Tasks can be N-levels deep, you can "reach up" to the Project object in your query using the "fields" argument to pull additional information. For example, here's how you could extend what you have to grab the Project's Name and Projected Completion Date:

```
/task/search?name=Name of Task&percentComplete=0&fields=project:name,project:projectedCompletionDate
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I couldn't figure out how fields work until your example, this is awesome :)